# How kafka producer works in asynchronous mode

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-kafka

I have a simple code to send a message

```
    private static void send(KafkaProducer<String, String> producer) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" before");
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test", "test"), (metadata, exception) -> {
            if (exception == null) {
                System.out.println(metadata.partition());
            } else {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" after");
    }
```

And kafka config

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9091");
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
```

My kafka is shutdown.

I expected if I call send twice

```
        send(producer);
        send(producer);
```

, I will get two `Thread before` records one after the other since we are working in asynchronous mode

```
Thread before
Thread before
```

But I see the start of processing the second record only after the error of the first

```
Thread[main,5,main] before
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
Thread[main,5,main] after
Thread[main,5,main] before
```

I think I misunderstood kafka's asynchronous mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first send request is blocking to create the topic.

Also, your `after` should be within the lamdba callback body.